# Some tool to debug CSS unexpected style?

Tags: c++, html, css

I'm developing a big website and I'm in trouble often with styles.
In this case, I have a 40px div height (from CSS class), but the computed value ends to 20px.

Is there a tool or something that can let me know why the height of this div is 20px instead 40px?

I don't want to figure out why it is 20px, I'm looking for a tool or a concrete way to reach why the final result is 20px instead 40px (maybe flex, maybe I don't know what rule in this case).

This is just a generic example, I'm bored of fighting against so many CSS rules and a huge web style hierarchy.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet which shows the problem - it's not really possible to debut just from an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't have a tool for you, but the answer is flex here.  That's how it works by default.  Items in a flex container have their shrink property set to 1.  You have to override this property on the list-items by setting `flex-shrink: 0`.

Comment: @jme11 certainly that was the issue. I'd love to have a way to debug this kind of things and reach out that `flex-shrink` was the rule causing that final height value.